# Photoshop scripting with Python COM. Duplicate and flatten problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, photoshop, win32com

I'm trying to merge some PS files, basically with two methods:

**1) Flatten, SelectAll, Copy, change ActiveDocument and Paste. This one return a TypeError in the first step.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\Merge.py", line 5, in <module>
    doc.flatten()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

*Inside Photoshop I can observe the document was flattened, but return this. stoping the script.*

**2) Duplicate LayerSet pointing to the targeted Document.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\Merge.py", line 27, in <module>
    appRef.activeDocument.LayerSets[0].duplicate(appRef.documents[0]);  
  File "C:\python27-64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

*Same Here! The LayerSet was duplicated*

- Photoshop CC 2014 64bits
- Python 2.7 64bits
- Win32com for python 2.7 64bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are troubles with win32com.

**comtypes** works pretty well! re-installing python 2.7 64bits. Check "Install for me only" instead "Install for all users" then install comtypes.